# How to give each hair particle system in one object its own color

Tags: texturing, hair, color

How to give each hair particle system its own color (ideally from a texture)?

Example: an object has two hair particle systems, one which is blue, second which is red. The mesh underneath is a third color or one of the previous two (but one can achieve that by assigning a material in edit mode to all the faces in the mesh).

Is there a way to assign a material to a particle system? **Multiple hair particle systems all seem to only be using the very first material in an object.**

Vertex groups can control so much, but not what color the hair particles have. There is a "textures" tab in particle settings, just below the vertex groups, but it doesn't seem to do anything color-related.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create 3 Material Slots and 3 Materials for your emitter object (1). In  this example, Blue and Red aren't assigned to any face.

For each Particle System, under Render/Material (2), select the desired material in the list.
[image]